# getting error No Launcher activity found! in creating a setting activity for a widget

Tags: android, widget

in writing a `widget` and after i tried to add a setting activity for my `widget` , i got the error  "No Launcher activity found!"

this is my `AndroidManifest.xml` :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.persianweather"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <receiver android:name="com.example.persianweather.Main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
        </intent-filter>
        <!-- This specifies the widget provider info -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.appwidget.provider"
            android:resource="@xml/widget" />
    </receiver>

    <activity
        android:name="com.example.persianweather.SettingActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_setting" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: from where your are starting activity

Answer (score 0):

`No Launcher activity found!` means that you not mentioned any activity on launching the application. Try to add these lines in manifest. To specify these MAIN and LAUNCHER in the the intent filter for the activity you want to start on launch like:

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Note: Multiple action tags in a single intent-filter tag will also cause the same error.

Answer (score 0):

Make your SettingActivity as launcher activity, Only then you will be able to proceed further,

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.persianweather.SettingActivity"
    android:label="@string/title_activity_setting" >
    <intent-filter >
        <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_CONFIGURE" />

    </intent-filter>

    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```